# Is there a way for HashSet to return the duplicate of an object?

Tags: java, collections, hashset

for example:

```
class SomeClass
{
    int x;
    int y;
    public SomeClass(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
            return false;
        SomeClass that = (SomeClass) o;
        return x == that.x;
    }

    public int hashCode()
    {
        return Objects.hash(x);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
HashSet<SomeClass> hs = new HashSet<>();
SomeClass a = new SomeClass(3, 5);
SomeClass b = new SomeClass(3, 6);
hs.add(a);
hs.add(b);
```

I know that the HashSet won't add `b`. But I want it to somehow return the object `a`, because `a` and `b` aren't exactly identical.

the HashSet will treat them as equal and won't add `b`, after the failed insertion I want to inspect the object `a`.

## tldr:

I need a method that can do something like `hs.getDuplicateOf(b)`, would that be possible?

Comment: Unclear. `add()` returns a `boolean`.

Comment: `if (hs.contains(b)) { SomeClass copy = hs.stream().filter(o -> o.equals(b)).findFirst().get(); }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a `HashMap` instead should suit your needs:

```
Map<SomeClass, SomeClass> map = new HashMap<>();
SomeClass a = new SomeClass(3, 5);
SomeClass b = new SomeClass(3, 6);
SomeClass previousValue = map.put(a, a);
// previousValue == null
previousValue = map.put(b, b);
// previousValue == a
```

This will keep `b` and remove `a` (from the map's values), use `putIfAbsent` instead of `put` if you need the opposite behaviour.

Rather hacky, but so are your `equals`/`hashCode` methods ;)

Comment: Well, it’s easy to extend this to a non-hacky solution, by simply using the value of `x` as key.

Answer (score 1):

`HashSet#add` returns if this set already contain the specified element. So, you could try:

```
if(!hs.add(b)) {
    System.out.println("b already exists");
}
```

Comment: I specifically want to check what is the "y" value of the object "a", which the equals() method does not depend on.

I want to say something like:

if(!hs.add(b)) {
    System.out.println("duplicate's y value is: " + hs.getDuplicateOf(b).y );
}